# Unable to search inserted Documents in Elastic Search Node

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have Set up a elastic search node on Azure and Implemented CRUD operations for the same using nest client while i have no problem inserting a new document in to the node but the inserted document is not visible for search though it can be seen in elasticsearch head in chrome extensions.

I have gone through documentation which suggest me to refresh the index after inserting yet no success in getting the inserted document in search results

```
public bool AddNewProductEL( string indexName, ProductTable product)
    {
        bool status = false;
        try
        {
            List<ProductTable> FinalList = new List<ProductTable>();
            ProductTable item = new ProductTable();
            item.ProductID = product.ProductID;
            item.ProductName = product.ProductName;
            string packing = (from t in entity.Packings where t.PackingID == product.PackingFID select t.PackingName).FirstOrDefault();
            item.PackingName = packing == null ? "" : packing;
            string manu = (from t in entity.Manufacturers where t.ManufacturerID == product.ManufacturerFID select t.ManufacturerName).FirstOrDefault();
            item.Manufacturername = manu == null ? "" : manu;
            item.ProductDescription = product.ProductDescription == null ? "" : product.ProductDescription;
            string brand = (from t in entity.Brands where t.BrandID == product.BrandFID select t.BrandName).FirstOrDefault();
            item.Brandname = brand == null ? "" : brand;
            item.ProductTypeFID = product.ProductTypeFID;
            FinalList.Add(item);

            foreach (var dt in FinalList)
            {                  
                var response = elasticClient.Index(dt, i => i
              .Index(indexName)
              .Type(TypeName.From<ProductTable>())
              .Id(dt.ProductID)
              .Refresh(Refresh.True));
                if (response.IsValid) { status = true; }
                var r = elasticClient.RefreshAsync(indexName);            
            }
           // System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" inserting product in elasticsearch status : - " + status);
            return status;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            status = false;
          //  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("error inserting product in elasticsearch : - " + e.Message + " inner exception :-" + e.InnerException);
            return status;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Share your mapping, there could be a possibility that you disabled indexing for the field on which you are trying to search the document.

Comment: this is my index creation code
        `var settings = new IndexSettings { NumberOfReplicas = 0, NumberOfShards = 2, RefreshInterval = 1 };
                var indexConfig = new IndexState
                {
                    Settings = settings
                };
                var res = elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c.InitializeUsing(indexConfig));`

Comment: and inserting values/documents in index 
`var response = elasticClient.Index(dt, i => i
                    .Index(indexName)
                    .Type(TypeName.From<ProductTable>())
                    .Id(dt.ProductID)
                    .Refresh(Refresh.True));`

Comment: share the mapping, or else if you have not defined any mapping, share a sample document that you are trying to index.